# Slick MSSQL inserting object with auto increment

Tags: sql-server, scala, slick

I've recently had to move a project over from MySQL to MSSQL. I'm using `IDENTITY(1,1)` on my id columns for my tables to match MySQL's auto-increment feature.

When I try to insert an object though, I'm getting this error:

```
[SQLServerException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'categories' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.]
```

Now after some research I found out that it's because I'm trying to insert a value for my id(0) on my tables. So for example I have an object Category

```
case class Category(
  id: Long = 0L,
  name: String
)
object Category extends Table[Category]("categories"){

  def name = column[String]("name", O.NotNull)
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

  def * = id ~ name <> (Category.apply _, Category.unapply _)

  def add(model:Category) = withSession{ implicit session =>
    Category.insert(model)
  }
  def remove(id:Long) = withSession{implicit session =>
    try{Some(Query(Category).filter(_.id === id).delete)}
    catch{case _ => None}
  }
}
```

Is there a way to insert my object into the database and ignoring the 0L without MSSQL throwing an SQLException? MySQL would just ignore the id's value and do the increment like it didn't receive an id.
I'd really rather not create a new case class with everything but the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redefining your `add` method like this and see if it works for you:

```
def add(model:Category) =  withSession{ implicit session =>
  Category.name.insert(model.name)
}
```

If you had more columns then you could have added a `forInsert` projection to your Category table class that specified all fields except `id`, but since you don't, this should work instead.

**EDIT**

Now if you do have more than 2 fields on your table objects, then you can do something like this, which is described in the Lifted Embedding documentation [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html#inserting):

```
case class Category(
  id: Long = 0L,
  name: String,
  foo:String
)
object Category extends Table[Category]("categories"){
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name", O.NotNull)
  def foo = column[String]("foo", O.NotNull)

  def * = id ~ name ~ foo <> (Category.apply _, Category.unapply _)

  def forInsert = name ~ foo <> (t => Category(0L, t._1, t._2), {(c:Category) => Some(c.name, c.foo)})

  def add(model:Category) =  withSession{ implicit session =>
    Category.forInsert insert model
  }
  def remove(id:Long) = withSession{implicit session =>
    try{Some(Query(Category).filter(_.id === id).delete)}
    catch{case _ => None}
  }

  def withSession(f: Session => Unit){

  }
}
```

Comment: Most of my objects have at least 6 fields, so is there a way I could do this projection without rewriting all of my fields? It seems very inelegant to rewrite all but one field. Because if I ever wanted to add a field it would have to be in multiple places.

Comment: @kingdamian42, I added more code around having more than two fields.  I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Yeah thanks, that's about what I've come up with. I just wish there was a way where I don't have to do so much hardcoding. Because now if I want to add something I have to add it to the case class, add a def in the object, add it to *, add it to forInsert, and of course add it to the database. It's just a lot to add and you'd think it could be consolidated into one spot. I guess this will have to do for now though, thanks.